# Signing an .apk when updating an application 

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have updated an android application and pushed it to the Market. On a nexus one it says that the update failed because of a signature issue. But it worked on other devices (Nexus S for instance).
By the way I used the same certificat than the one I used to push the first version.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove all debug versions of your app on your nexus before installing the "market" version.

Eclipse + ADT plugin signs apps with a debug certificate when in debug mode, and it is not compatible with the certificate you use to publish on the market. Your android phone won't allow an update of an app if it is *not* signed with the same certificate as the older version.

Go to Settings >> applications >> manage applications, and remove your package signed with your debug certificate before installing the market version.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks, it was that! I completely forgot that I installed a debug version on my bosse's nexus one :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a development / debug build on your Nexus One? if so, then dev builds are signed with a different certificate to release builds and you will encounter this issue. If all else fails, uninstall the app manually before trying to install from the market.